# Arduino Uno wiring and code with Parallax PMB-688

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, wires, tinygps

I'm new to Arduino GPS and am wondering if I could be pointed in the right direction regarding code and wiring when hooking up my Parallax PMB-688 to an Arduino Uno

Comment: Try this: http://playground.arduino.cc/Tutorials/GPS -

Answer (score 1):

The following link was suggested in the comments by user [PhillyNJ](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/490/phillynj). Adding it here as a community wiki answer:

- http://playground.arduino.cc/Tutorials/GPS